# Wine no longer works after upgrading to 18.04

Tags: upgrade, wine

After upgrading to Ubuntu 18, I can no longer run any programs in wine. Below is the output when I tried calling wine through terminal. Any ideas?

`gary@zen:/media/gary/files/wine/drive_c/Games/Railroad Tycoon/II$ wine RT2_TSC.EXE 
err:wincodecs:PngEncoder_CreateInstance Failed writing PNG because unable to find libpng12.so.0
fixme:ole:CoCreateInstanceEx no instance created for interface {00000103-a8f2-4877-ba0a-fd2b6645fb94} of class {27949969-876a-41d7-9447-568f6a35a4dc}, hres is 0x80004005
err:menubuilder:convert_to_native_icon error 0x80004005 creating bitmap encoder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download LibPNG 1.2 packages manually from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS [repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/libpng12-0) and install them with:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb

sudo apt-get install ./libpng12-*.deb
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. That got me past that hurdle but now I see this: 

wine: Unhandled page fault on read access to 0x00000004 at address 0x7ea94426 (thread 0009), starting debugger...
winedbg: Internal crash at 0x7e82d426

Comment: I would suggest to install the game from PlayOnLinux (`sudo apt-get install playonlinx`) and specify older version of Wine if it would crash even here.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up upgrading Ubuntu to the development version, after which Wine started working again. I'm not sure why, but it did.